# Laravel Form Looping Not Rendering Completely

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My View

```
<tbody>
@foreach($categories as $category)
<tr>
<td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $category->slug }}</td>
<td>{{ ($category->TermTaxonomy ? $category->TermTaxonomy->description : '') }}</td>
<td>
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['admin_posts_categories_destroy', $category->term_id]]) }}
{{ Form::submit('Delete'); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

then result in inspect element [image: first form not rendering]
so i can't delete the first row , but i can delete the other , why this things happen ? and how to fix it. already try in the other browser and still same.

Comment: That view code can't possibly give that output.

Comment: but why form render successfully in second and third row ?

Comment: can you be more specific about what the expected output would look like?

Comment: is `$category->term_id` available for all the rows? I think, for the first row, it's not available, for this reason the form can not be rendered.

Comment: thanks all , just missing `{{ Form::close() }}` in the first form (static form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind , in have 2 form in my view the first is static form to add term, the second is loop form for restful delete, and missing `{{ Form::close() }}` in the first form (static) , so just put `{{ Form::close() }}` in the first form (static) and both form static and looping work like a charm. thanks for all.